# Get current class through declaration in inherited class

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net, and want to simplify the usage. Right now, in every class I use logging (which is almost all all classes), I have to write:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    try
    {
       // do something
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       log.Error("Problem doing something", ex);
    }
}
```

What I would really like to do is to put the first declaration in another class, which I could inherit wherever I need logging:

```
 public class MyClass : Logging
 {
    try
    {
       // do something
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       log.Error("Problem doing something", ex);
    }
 }

public class Logging
{
    public static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
}
```

But, if I do this, the problem is that

```
 System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

...ends up picking up the class name Logging, which is no good for the log. How do I get it to pick up the class name of the class where the inherited logging class is used?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should not use inheritance but composition for your problem.

Comment: @Anders: Use a `static class` with `static method` instead.... as `@Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets` already answered ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inherit all your classes from Logging class then you won't be able to inherit classes from any other classes and create inheritance structure because C# does not support multiple inheritance. You really need to use composition not inheritance.

You can simplify calls to your logger by creating static helper class:

```
public static class LoggerHelper
{
    public static void WriteError(string message,Exception ex, Type type)
    {
        var log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(type);
        log.Error(message, ex);
    }
}
```

And then in you classes you will call it like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LoggerHelper.WriteError("Problem doing something", ex, this.GetType());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you - good solution. And you're right (like others have also pointed out), inheritance does not make sense.

Comment: ??? A non-static method inside a static class? A public static local variable inside a method?

Comment: I think this could be further improved by turning WriteError into an extension method, so that the type could be infered from the calling object. Then, you'd just need to pass the text and exception to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

So you're gonna make all your classes inherit from `Logging`? 
Inheritance is not meant for code reuse, it's meant to represent a "is a kind of" relationship between two domain entities. Don't abuse it.

What you need is composition.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
}
```

`MyClass` *has* a logger, it *is not* a logger.

Comment: Thanks - point taken. You show the same solution as the one I already have. Just thought there was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: @Anders, if you want to make it _cleaner_, you might want to take a look at "dependency injection", and then use some IoC frameworks like Castle Windsor, and have it inject a logger into your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your base class like so:

```
 public abstract class Logging
 {
    public readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
 }
```

`this.GetType()` will always return the concrete type.